# ForeignObject not working in IE

Tags: d3.js

I have my text appended to div inside a foreign object.
The text renders fine in chrome but does not show at all in the IE.
I have researched on it and it seems that IE does not support foreign object.
Is there a work-around that will make it work in IE??

P.S. I am using d3.js to create circles and my foreign object is in the circle.
I have used foreign object to overcome text alignment issues.

Thanks for the help in Advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IE9 does not support `foreignObject`.  Check out the "Browser Compatibility" table at the bottom of the MDN page: [foreignObject](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/foreignObject).